# Удалить элементы из всего листа (не получается)

Tags: r

У меня есть лист `vecs` с векторами внутри

```
set.seed(356)
vecs <- list()
for(i in 1:10) vecs[[i]] <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
```

вот

```
 head(vecs)
    [[1]]
      [1]  74  32   2  18  52  85  51  96  17  66   2  92  76  95  75  62  55  40  12  99  43  10  30  70  52
     [26]  98  61  34  26  37  38  48  81  53  49  18  20  97  59  49  58  44  13   2  90  27   6  39  90  36
     [51]   6  77  25  71  35  78  37  90  96  90  31 100  27  34  59  69  60  14  87  77   2  71  69   2  25
     [76]  47  87  91  33  13  44  31  39  70  25  82  73  72  50  21  51  86   6  36  88  74   7  15  99  13
    
    [[2]]
      [1] 25  9 73  9 57  8 16 81 75 61 86  6 80 34 43 92 42 56 85 15 50 93 21 61 95 64  9 27 79 76 74 78 48 47
     [35] 67 91 30 45 13 84 55 58 20 64 60 12 69 16 68 82 62 21 49 18 19 62 85 80 35 83 83 25 33 85 21  3 44 25
     [69] 70  3  8 43 38 91 98 32 27 72 89 33 26 21 40 10 67  2 90 25  9 36 61 85 94 34 29 27 84 40 46  3
    ..................
    .........
    ....
    ..
```

Мне нужно удалить из листа `vecs` такие элементы которые встречаются меньше `n` раз и вернуть обратно `vecs` только уже без этих элементов

```
li2 <- vecs  # создадим новый лист
n <- 5    # зададим число "n"
```

Посчитаем сколько раз каждый элемент встречается во всем листе `vecs`

```
tb <- table(unlist(vecs)) # весь лист перекодируем в вектор
> tb

  **1**   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  **15**  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27 
  **5**  16  11  10   7  11   7  11  11  10  10  14  13  10   **5**   6   6  11   8  11  12  10   6   8  14  16   9 
 28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  **38**  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54 
  9  11  12   9   7   8  15   8  11   7   **5**  12  10  12   7  10  12   7  11  14   7  11   8  14  10   9   6 
 55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  **76**  77  78  79  80  81 
  7   8   8   8   8  12  17  12  12   6   8  10  14  10  14  15  12  11   8  15  13   **5**   9  11   9   7   7 
 82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
 12   8  15  12   5  10  13   8  15   6  11   6  13  11  10   5  13   9  12
```

Видно что есть значения которые встречаются 5 или меньше раз, вычислим их и назовем `bad.values`

```
 bad.values <- as.numeric(  names(tb[tb<=n])  )
> bad.values
[1]  1 15 38 76 86 97
```

Дальше пишу функцию `f` которая принимает вектор , проверяет в нем наличие `bad.values` и удаляет их

```
f <- function(x)  x[  -which(x %in% bad.values)  ]
```

Проходим по каждому вектору в списке `vecs2` и применяем фун. `f`

```
vecs2 <- lapply(vecs2, f)
```

Теперь проверяем "очищенный" лист vecs2 , минимальное количество повторений элементов должно быть больше 5-ти, а по факту

```
min(table(unlist(vecs2)))
[1] 3
```

Вот так выглядит "очищенный" лист vecs2, какие то вектора вообще удалены....

```
> vecs2
[[1]]
 [1]  74  32   2  18  52  85  51  96  17  66   2  92  95  75  62  55  40  12  99  43  10  30  70  52  98  61
[27]  34  26  37  48  81  53  49  18  20  59  49  58  44  13   2  90  27   6  39  90  36   6  77  25  71  35
[53]  78  37  90  96  90  31 100  27  34  59  69  60  14  87  77   2  71  69   2  25  47  87  91  33  13  44
[79]  31  39  70  25  82  73  72  50  21  51   6  36  88  74   7  99  13

[[2]]
 [1] 25  9 73  9 57  8 16 81 75 61  6 80 34 43 92 42 56 85 50 93 21 61 95 64  9 27 79 74 78 48 47 67 91 30
[35] 45 13 84 55 58 20 64 60 12 69 16 68 82 62 21 49 18 19 62 85 80 35 83 83 25 33 85 21  3 44 25 70  3  8
[69] 43 91 98 32 27 72 89 33 26 21 40 10 67  2 90 25  9 36 61 85 94 34 29 27 84 40 46  3

[[3]]
integer(0)

[[4]]
 [1] 13 25 69 90  3 60 24 64 33 94 66 90 20 71 14 29  3 67 11 21 57 88 24 84 99 65 54 59 52 72 89 71 39 69
[35] 94 25 65 80 47 17 61 60 73 71  2 92 99 65 80 51 82 78 18 46 79 60 74 39 41 75 39 11 98 61 63 22 22 14
[69] 48 41 46  2  8 63 81 96 43 66 87  5 47 78 41 30 88 31 62 81 25 85 44 54 75 57  6 69
```

Помогите понять что я делаю не так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сами отвечаете на вопрос - в функции f удаляете весь вектор.
Вот корректный вариант:

```
vecs2 <- lapply(vecs, function(x) ifelse(x %in% bad.values, NaN, x) )
min(table(unlist(vecs2)))
```